# Hodge star operator on complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-forms, hodge-theory

The Hodge star is defined as
\begin{equation}
\alpha\wedge\overline{\star\beta} = \langle\alpha,\beta\rangle(\star1),\quad
\alpha,\beta\in\Omega^{p,q}(M).
\end{equation}
Here the inner product $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle
= \frac1{p!q!}\sum_{I,\bar J}\alpha_{I,\bar J}\overline{\beta_{I,\bar J}}.
\end{equation}

Applying this definition for $\alpha = \beta = 1$,
$1\wedge\overline{\ast1} = \langle1,1\rangle(\ast1) = (\ast1)$.
On the other hand, for $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = i$
\begin{equation}
1\wedge\overline{\ast i}
= \langle 1,i\rangle(\ast1)
= -i(\ast1)
= (-i)1\wedge\overline{\ast1}
= 1\wedge\overline{i(\ast1)}.
\end{equation}
Then, $\ast i = i(\ast1)$.
Does it imply $\ast$ is a linear operator?

However, I found that $\ast$ is anti-linear here
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/162861/190058

My derivation above is wrong?

P.S. For the Hodge star,
the transformation for basis is
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\ast(\theta^I\bar\theta^{\bar J})
= \frac{(-i)^{n^2}}{(n-p)!(n-q)!}\varepsilon^{I\bar J}_{\quad I'\bar J'}\bar\theta^{I'}\theta^{\bar J'},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\ast(\bar\theta^I\theta^{\bar J})
= \frac{i^{n^2}}{(n-p)!(n-q)!}\varepsilon^{I\bar J}_{\quad I'\bar J'}\theta^{I'}\bar\theta^{\bar J'},
\end{equation}
where the last equation is the complex conjugation of the first one.
($\because$ $\text{c.c.}(\ast\beta) 
= \text{c.c.}(\ast a + i\ast b)
= \ast a - i\ast b
= \ast(a - i\ast b)
= \ast(\text{c.c.}(\beta))$)

On the other hand, by changing the order of basis,
\begin{align}
\ast(\bar\theta^{\bar J}\theta^I)
= \frac{(-i)^{n^2}}{(n-p)!(n-q)!}\varepsilon^{\bar JI}_{\quad\bar J'I'}\theta^{\bar J'}\bar\theta^{I'}.
\end{align}
For the first one and this one, which is correct?

Comment: Without checking anything, this *might* be because physicists tend to use a different convention for inner products than mathematicians. In particular they typiclaly require that $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is conjugate linear in the *first* variable, while the mathematicians' convention is to have the inner product be conjugate linear in the *second* variable.

Comment: @kahen So if we use the physicists convention, $\star$ is antilinear while if we use the mathematicians convention $\star$ is linear?

Comment: Please do not use $i$ as an index when working with complex forms.

Comment: Did I use $i$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few conventions here. You can check whether it is linear as follows: $$\forall\alpha:\alpha\wedge \overline{\ast(k\beta)}=\langle \alpha,k\beta\rangle (\ast1)=\bar k\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle (*1)=\alpha\wedge\overline{k\ast(\beta)}\Longrightarrow \ast(k\beta)= k\ast(\beta)$$

On the other hand, it is also common in the literature to define the Hodge star operator by the equation $\alpha\wedge\ast\beta=\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle(\ast1)$. Likewise, we can check $$\forall\alpha:\alpha\wedge\ast(k\beta)=\langle\alpha,k\beta\rangle(\ast1)=\bar k\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle(\ast 1)=\alpha\wedge\bar k\ast(\beta)\Longrightarrow\ast(k\beta)=\bar k\ast(\beta)$$

This becomes antilinear. Note that the first one sends a $(p,q)$-form to $(n-q,n-p)$ form meanwhile the second definition sends a $(p,q)$-form to $(n-p,n-q)$ form.

Comment: In my textbook the first convention is used.
Here $\ast^2\alpha = (-1)^{p+q}\alpha$ for $(p,q)$-form $\alpha$. 
This property is independent of the convention?

Comment: Yes I think so. One property is that $\ast$ preserves the metric, whether it is linear or antilinear. (Really they are the same up to conjugation).

Comment: In my textbook, the Hodge star operation is given by 
$$
\overline{\ast\beta} 
= \frac{i^{n^2}}{(n-p)!(n-q)!p!q!}\beta_{I\bar J}\varepsilon^{I\bar J}_{\;\; I'\bar J'}\theta^{I'}\wedge\bar\theta^{J'}.
$$
To check $\ast^2 = (-1)^{p+1}$, I would like to find the expression without complex conjugation. 
Is this the correct form?
\begin{equation}
\ast(\theta^I\wedge\bar\theta^{\bar J}) 
= \frac{(-i)^{n^2}}{(n-p)!(n-q)!}\varepsilon^{I\bar J}_{\;\;\; I'\bar J'}\bar\theta^{I'}\wedge\theta^{\bar J'}.
\end{equation}